# warning C4834: отмена возвращаемого значения функции с атрибутом " nodiscard"

Tags: c++

Имеем простой класс с функцией, которая помечена атрибутом `nodiscard`

```
class A {
  public:
    [[nodiscard]] decltype(auto) get_m_numbers() const {
      return (_numbers);
    }

  private:
    std::vector<int> _numbers;
}

int main() {
  A my_a;
  for(auto number: my_a.get_m_numbers()){
    std::cout << number;
  }
}
```

На что VS выдает предупреждение:

```
warning C4834: отмена возвращаемого значения функции с атрибутом "nodiscard"
```

Я думал, что foreach разворачивается в такую конструкцию

```
{
  vector<int>::iterator __iter = begin(my_a.get_m_numbers()); // (1)
  vector<int>::iterator __end  = end(my_a.get_m_numbers());   // (2)

  for(; __iter != __end; ++__iter) {
    auto number = *__iter;
    { 
      std::cout << number;     
    }
  }
}
```

Но тогда я не понимаю, откуда предупреждение. Ведь результат функции используется в местах `(1)` и `(2)`.

Comment: [Не воспроизводится](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/je3qqEbsc).

Comment: VC++ 2019 с `/W4` — никаких замечаний.

Comment: я думаю, что эта функция используется ещё где то и вот оно и дает такую ошибку (предупреждение)

Comment: Странно, может студию пора обновить

Comment: может дадите больше данных? версию студии, весь код примера?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что если собрать проект с помощью команды cmake `-G "Visual Studio 15 2017"`, то будет использоваться набор инструментов `v140`. При сборке с помощью `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019 " -T v141` такого предупреждения нет.